# Read a zip an write it to an other file python

Tags: python, zip

I want to read a file and write it back out.  Here's my code:

```
   file = open( zipname , 'r' )
   content =  file.read() 
   file.close()

   alt = open('x.zip', 'w')
   alt.write(content )
   alt.close()
```

This doesn't work, why?????

Edit:

The rewritten file is corrupt
(python 2.7.1 on windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read and write in the binary mode, 'rb' and 'wb':

```
f = open(zipname , 'rb')
content =  f.read() 
f.close()

alt = open('x.zip', 'wb')
alt.write(content )
alt.close()
```

The reason the text mode didn't work on Windows is that the newline translation from '\r\n' to '\r' mangled the binary data in the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for this, drove me nuts when trying to upload a Zipfile to Dropbox (on Windows, OSX was fine).

Answer (score 6):

From [this bit of the manual](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

Comment: It gets even worse with Python 3. In Python 3 encodings are applied at read/write time and all strings are Unicode. In plain speech: A lot more than just the line-endings can change, and on all platforms. This means folks need to mark files when they're binary on all platforms or they'll have a lot harder time porting to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

If I run this program on my OS X or Linux box, it works exactly as you would expect.  The file `x.zip` has exactly the same checksum as the original zip file and is not corrupt.  I believe that Windows is one of the platforms where you need to explicitly open files in binary mode; try:

```
file = open(zipname, 'rb')
```